# Resque jobs stuck in pending state

Tags: redis, resque

My workers are not working correctly.

My scheduler it's apparently not working. However, when I manually en-queue something, I can see it it's successfully added, however it gets stuck in pending state.

When I mean manually I mean something like this:

```
Resque.enqueue(MyJob,<params>)
```

Those get stuck on pending state and the other ones, the one on my resque_scheduler are not being en-queue at all.

I tried restarting the workers and it doesn’t work either.

Any ideas what might be happening? If you need more info/dumps let me know.

Thanks.

---

a) are using resque_scheduler if yes are you starting it: Yes, I'm using it. And I just did a `rake resque:scheduler RAILS_ENV=production`

```
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Reloading Schedule
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Loading Schedule
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Scheduling c_aggregator_job 
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Scheduling ca_aggregator_job 
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Scheduling l_history_aggregator 
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Scheduling target_aggregator 
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Scheduling view_count_aggregator 
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Scheduling searches_view_aggregator 
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Scheduling b_view_count_aggregator_job 
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Scheduling y_aggregator 
2013-09-11 16:38:08 Schedules Loaded
```

So I think it is working, right?

b) which version of resque

```
gem 'resque', '1.23.0'
gem 'resque-scheduler', :require => 'resque_scheduler'
```

c) have you re-started resque workers rake task 
No, I used:

```
sudo service resque-workers start/stop
```

Here's the script:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          resque-server
# Required-Start:    $network $named $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $network $named $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5                                                                                                                               
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6                                                                                                                                 
### END INIT INFO                 

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=`which rake`
DAEMON_ARGS='resque:work'
DESC="Resque workers script"
PWD=/webapps/noomii/offline/
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

if [ ! -d /var/run/resque ]; then
        mkdir -p /var/run/resque
fi

start_resque() {
        start-stop-daemon --start  --quiet --chdir $PWD --chuid capistrano:capistrano --make-pidfile --background --pidfile /var/run/resque/rake.pid \
                --exec  $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE=high,medium,low 
}

stop_resque() {
    start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo  --pidfile /var/run/resque/rake.pid
}

status_resque() {
        status_of_proc -p "/var/run/resque/rake.pid" 
}

case "$1" in
    start)
  log_begin_msg "Starting $DESC"
  start_resque
  log_end_msg $?
  ;;
    stop)
  log_begin_msg "Stopping $DESC"
  stop_resque
  log_end_msg $?
  ;;
    status)
      status_resque
        ;;
    restart|force-reload)
  log_begin_msg "Restarting $DESC"
  stop_resque
  sleep 1
  start_resque
  log_end_msg $?
  ;;
    *)
  echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}" >&2
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

d) is the queue specified correct in rake task
Yes, it is.

Comment: Can you attach some code please :)

Comment: The thing is I don't know what would be useful to post. @Viren

Comment: Couple of thing a) are using `resque_scheduler` if yes are you starting it b) which version of resque c) have you re-started resque workers `rake` task d) is the queue specified correct in rake task

Comment: I added all that info into my question. Check it out @Viren

Comment: Ohh I see you see you added the rake task as script can you attach that code as well .One last thing If you are using `Resque.enqueue` why do you want resque_scheduler after all

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37194/discussion-between-viren-and-content01)

Comment: JFI do you see the resque worker running also is it a rails app if yes can you open the console and confirm whether the  message are getting pushed into redis or not all you have do is push message via console into the queue and Inspect the before and after count of your queue like this `Resque.redis.llen "queue:high"` also attach the output of outputs of `Resque.redis.smembers "queues"`

Comment: Glad you manage to get that working :)

Answer (score 4):

For any n00bs out there like me, setting up Resque on Heroku for the first time. Make sure you add a Resque worker in your apps Resources section.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so apparently my old scripts were not working.

I executed:

```
rake resque:scheduler RAILS_ENV=production
QUEUE=high,aggregators bundle exec rake resque:work RAILS_ENV=production
```

and all started working again :)

Thank you very much for you help and I'm aware that this was a newbie issue :)